# Continue the definition of a string over multiple lines in TCL without adding a space

Tags: tcl

I want to define a variable in tcl, filePath, to contain the path to a file. However, the file path is long and causes the line to exceed 80 characters. When I use a backslash to continue the line, tcl automatically adds a space into the string which I don't want. Currently, my definition is

```
set filePath "documents/school/2016/homework/ECE102/assignment_2/setupfiles/contantDefinitions"
```

but when I try

```
set filePath "documents/school/2016/homework/ECE102/assignment_2/\
        setupfiles/contantDefinitions"
```

tcl will assign filePath `"documents/school/2016/homework/ECE102/assignment_2/ setupfiles/contantDefinitions"`

How can I split it over multiple lines without adding a space?

Comment: I edited your post to add code formatting, does it render really like what you have in your code ? (if yes, remove the indentation of your second line which is probabaly what cause the space)

Comment: @tensibai thanks for the updated formatting, that is what I have in my code. However, I tried removing the tab and it didn't remove the space. Additionally, the tab is necessary to comply with the style guide I am using

Comment: if I understand well, you're breaki'g your code for style, style guides are recommendations and it's absolutely ok to break them when it's the proper solution ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
set filePath [file join documents/school/2016/homework/ECE102/assignment_2/\
    setupfiles/contantDefinitions]
```

The `file join` command is to be preferred when putting pieces of a path together, but as long as there is a slash at the end of the first piece, `append` will do:

```
append filePath documents/school/2016/homework/ECE102/assignment_2/\
    setupfiles/contantDefinitions
```

Just make sure `filePath` is empty or nonexistent before this invocation.

If one wants to avoid the line continuations:

```
set filePath documents/school/2016/homework/ECE102/assignment_2/
set filePath [file join $filePath setupfiles/contantDefinitions]

set filePath documents/school/2016/homework/ECE102/assignment_2/
append filePath setupfiles/contantDefinitions
```

The Tcl interpreter has no problem with 80+ character lines, the only reason to break definitions up is that it looks neater and/or line length is a part of a set of coding guidelines.

(Those who have a recent version of Tcl can use `string cat` in the same manner as `file join` is used above.)

Documentation: [append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm), [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: could also mention `append`

Comment: @Peter thanks for the response, but it seems unnecessary to split the file name into two variables. I was hoping for a slightly cleaner/ simpler solution

Comment: My 2 cts: style guides are recommendations which can be break when the compliance add complexity. (upvoted the answer as absolutely valid)

Comment: @BenCheng: added another variant that might suit you better. This was probably what Brad Lanam hinted at in his comment.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the parts in braces to form a list and then join the pieces

```
set filePath [join {
    documents/school/2016/homework/ECE102/assignment_2/
    setupfiles/contantDefinitions
} ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just crashed into the same problem as described in the original question; although workarounds are suggested, none of the responses address the question of the extra space.  Even when I start the continuation text of a long string in the first character of the second line Tcl is still adding a space to the string at the point of the join.  Don Libes (in his book Exploring Expect, p33) suggests that "a backslash-newline-whitespace sequence is replaced by a single space".  Tcl (at least v8.6 anyway) will also replace backslash-newline with a single space.  Even if the original spec says it should do just that, this seems very counterintuitive to this newcomer!